# Необходимо создать класс Интернет-магазин (название магазина, список товаров та цен на них в этом магазине)

Tags: java, коллекции

Помогите это сделать, я недавно начала учить коллекции и немного не понимаю, как это сделать. У меня есть класс ProductSearchSrvice (список интернет-магазинов)

```
class ProductSearchSrvice {
    private String name;

    public ProductSearchSrvice(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Online store {" +
                "name = '" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

И есть класс, где выводятся эти классы

```
public class Lab10 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<ProductSearchSrvice> list = new ArrayList<>();

        ProductSearchSrvice shop_1 = new ProductSearchSrvice("Rozetka");
        ProductSearchSrvice shop_2 = new ProductSearchSrvice("OLX");
        ProductSearchSrvice shop_3 = new ProductSearchSrvice("HIKVISION");

        list.add(shop_1);
        list.add(shop_2);
        list.add(shop_3);

        ProductSearchSrvice shop_1FromCollection = list.get(0);
        ProductSearchSrvice shop_2FromCollection = list.get(1);
        ProductSearchSrvice shop_3FromCollection = list.get(2);

        System.out.println(shop_1FromCollection);
        System.out.println(shop_2FromCollection);
        System.out.println(shop_3FromCollection);
    }
}
```

Я немного не могу понять, как определить название магазина в классе Интернет-магазин, если оно есть в другом классе, и как потом вывести элементы этого класса на экран.

Comment: (C) переведи...

Comment: `ProductSearchSrvice ` - это никакой не сервис, это просто Entity, я бы назвал его просто `Store`. Не понятно что именно нужно сделать

Answer (score -1):

```
С java не знаком но могу посоветовать сделать так пример приведу на java-script

Во-первых у вас не очень хорошее название для класса, больше подходит для функции(метода)ProductSearchSrvice, я его заменю например ShopList
итак поехали:



   "use strict";
    (function(){

    //создам ф-ию  которая создает объект(класс)

    function createClass(){
      return {};
    }
    //И создам для удобства отладки
    function log(el){
      return console.log(el);
    }

    //-----Начало нашего кода----------
    var ShopList,ShopCloneList;
    //Создали класс  RenderContent будет принадлежать ему
    ShopList = createClass();
    ShopList.shops=[{
      "name": "Магазин обуви",
      "descr": "Классный магазин обуви",
      },
      {
        "name": "Магазин велосипедов",
        "descr": "Шикарный магазин велосипедов"

      },
      {
         "name" : "Магазин косметики",
         "descr": "Доступная косметика"
      }
      ];
    // log(ShopList.shops);
    ShopList.renderContent = function(){
      for(var key in ShopList.shops ){
        var res = ShopList.shops[key].name;
        var res = ShopList.shops[key].descr;
        log(res);
      }

    }
    ShopList.renderContent();

    //Создали еще один класс
    ShopCloneList = createClass();
    //создали метод этого класса
    ShopCloneList.renderContentCopy = function(){
        for(var key in ShopList.shops ){
        var res = ShopList.shops[key].name;
        var res = ShopList.shops[key].descr;
        log(res);
      }
    //или вызвали метод другого класса
    ShopList.renderContent();
    //или присвоили
    ShopCloneList.renderContentCopy =ShopList.renderContent();
    };
    //Вызвали метод класса ShopCloneList
    ShopCloneList.renderContentCopy(); 
    //Но все же лучше унаследовать метод класса от другого например так:
    //но работать это не будет потому что мы создали класс без //ключевого слово new 
//раскомментируйте если создаете через new;
    //ShopCloneList.prototype = Object.create(ShopList.prototype);
    //ShopCloneList.prototype.renderContent();
    })();

А, в общем то полистайте получше темы OОП(наследование, инкапсуляция полиморфизм)А, так же что такое классы и объекты потому что я заметил, что вы путаете эти понятия;
```